# How can I directly assign a value to a dataframe using chain indexing?

Tags: python, pandas

What I am doing is as follows:

```
for i in range(0, len(x.index)-1):
    x['Low'][i][x['Low'][i] == 0.0] =  np.mean(avg_low)
```

Basically, I have a dataframe called x and I want to access the column 'Low' within that dataframe and a particular row i. If that element in the dataframe is equal to 0.0, I want to update that value to np.mean(avg_low). For some reason, when I print the entire dataframe, nothing is changed and all the values are still equal to 0.0 when they should have been updated. My concern is that I am modifying a view instead of the actual dataframe when I am using this type of chain indexing. The documentation was a bit confusing with respect to when something returns a view or not, so I wanted clarification for this specific example. Thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify, a view is a reference to the original dataframe, a copy is a copy, so changes made to a view will be reflected in the original df, whilst they are not for a copy. It is unclear what you are trying to do here, given BrenBarn's answer didn't satisfy what you want, could you clarify further. At the moment I don't see the difference between doing `x.loc[x['Low']== 0.0, 'Low'] = np.mean(avg_low)` and your iterative approach

Comment: What you are doing currently gives rise to what is referred to as chain indexing which may or may not work. In your case it is not working, it is preferable to use the newer forms of indexing such as `loc`,`iloc` and `ix`.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to do `x.ix[x['Low'][i] == 0.0, 'Low'] = np.mean(avg_low)`.

Also, I'm not sure exactly what your DataFrame is like, but I think you should be able to do `x.ix[x['Low'] == 0, 'Low'] = np.mean(avg_low)` to set all the values at once, without having to iterate.

Comment: I don't want to change them all at once, as the mean is changing. Now I am getting a KeyError: 0L :\

Comment: I think it is better to use loc: `x.loc[x['Low'] == 0.0, 'Low'] = np.mean(avg_low)` I was told that you should use `loc` unless you cannot by Jeff